# Find One Query not running in Couchdb

Tags: view, couchdb, postman

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/test1/_view/test1/by_date?key="2009/01/30 18:04:11"
```

seems to be correct but not running....

here are the documents that i hv stored in database test

```
 {
  "_id":"biking",
  "_rev":"AE19EBC7654",
  "title":"Biking",
  "body":"My biggest hobby is mountainbiking. The other day...",
  "date":"2009/01/30 18:04:11"
 }

{
 "_id":"bought-a-cat",
 "_rev":"4A3BBEE711",
 "title":"Bought a Cat",
 "body":"I went to the the pet store earlier and brought home a little kitty...",
 "date":"2009/02/17 21:13:39"
}
{
"_id":"hello-world",
"_rev":"43FBA4E7AB",
"title":"Hello World",
"body":"Well hello and welcome to my new blog...",
"date":"2009/01/15 15:52:20"
}
```

I want to find single document (one with biking id)....

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your view is indeed `test1/by_date`, then the `/` might be the problem. You can try to URL-encode it as `%2F` so your query becomes:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/test1/_view/test1%2Fby_date?key="2009/01/30 18:04:11"
```

but I'd rather remove the slash from the name. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Can you post your map function?

Comment: here it is                                                    function(doc) {
if(doc.date && doc.title)  
emit(doc.date, doc.title);
}

Comment: I just tested it, it works for me in CouchDB 1.6.0 using `%2F`. Take a look at the log, it will probably tell you more about the error you get.